# SQL Server - Force INSERT statement to use varchar instead of int

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, insert, type-conversion

I'm trying to make a large insert to a new table in SQL Server that's set up with a particular column of type `varchar(56)`. Most of the values for that column in the insert rows are integer values, but placed inside quotes (i.e. '6'). There are, of course, a number of non-numeric values in there as well.

I understand that SQL server will implicitly convert a `varchar` column to `int` if it sees a lot of values that can be converted (http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-245.aspx is where I got that from. Only thing I've found online so far that at least seems to hit close to the problem I'm encountering.)

Is there any way to force it to *not* do that? I'd really rather not have to sort through all these rows to insert the text-valued rows first and then the numeric-valued rows.

#### Example

```
insert into [MyDB].[dbo].[Questions] (
     MAP_SRC
    ,Q_ID    
    ,R_ID    
    ,R_TXT   
    ,TEXT_1  
    ,TEXT_2  
    ,EXT_ID      
    ,EXT_Q_ID    
    ,EXT_VALUE   
    ,EXT_VALUE_2
    ,EXT_VALUE_3
)    
values
     ('D','1','1','',null, null,'1','N32','date txt','Date','')
    ,('D','2','2','',null, null,'2','N33','2','','')
```

...and so on. It's the `EXT_VALUE` column which is causing the issues. I've tried inserting the text-valued rows first to try to establish that the column is supposed to be `varchar` and not `int`, and putting one such row at the beginning of the inserts, but it's all for naught so far.

Comment: Please add a minimum example. How are you inserting this values? INSERT INTO TABLE SELECT .....?

Comment: Data types section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql) has useful information on what's happening. The query never actually gets as far as trying the insert, the datatype of EXT_VALUE is actually irrelevant to the problem (although that's not immediately clear).

Comment: @GarethLyons - sounds like that should be an answer to me....

Comment: Where do you get "SQL server will implicitly convert a varchar column to int if it sees a lot of values that can be converted"?   The column is what you defined it.   The data coming in does not define the column type.   SQL will attempt in implicit cast of the DATA if it does not match.  Please post data and column definitons to reproduce the problem.  And post the exact error.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is cast it to `VARCHAR(56)`

Ex:

```
INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (Field1, Field2, Field3)
SELECT Field11, Field12, CAST(Field13 AS VARCHAR(56))
FROM   ANOTHER_TABLE;
```

I'd suggest you to check for unquoted values in your insert sentences.